# Can BaseUser of FOSUserBundle extend my own class?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

My business case has a hierarchy above the user class (e.g. a contact only or a member without logins). But now I'm worried how the BaseUser which I have to extend from the FOSUserBundle can extend my Member class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand what is Your member class but in [FOS docs](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) its written

> Your first job, then, is to create the
>   User class for your application. This class can look and act however
>   you want: add any properties or methods you find useful. This is your
>   User class.
>
> The bundle provides base classes which are already mapped for most
>   fields to make it easier to create your entity.

You don't have to extend BaseUser, it is provided just to make installation easier. it should work if You copy it to Your own bundle and make it extend Your `member` class.

Comment: `Member` class represents a member of a association, but a member is not necessarily a user in the application. So simply copy the content of the FOS `BaseUser` and therefore implement `UserInterface` with copied code ^^ and extend my Member class.